# Using keep, discard and filter to keep data frames in a list of data frames

Tags: r, purrr

I have some experience in purrr but trying to figure out if this is the best use case for keep() or discard. I have a list of data frames as following

```
df1
A      B     C
1      0     4
2      0     5
3      0     6

df2
A      B     C
4      1     0
5      7     9
6      8     0

df_list = list(df1,df2)
```

Obviously, I made the above data up. The basic idea is to keep the dataframe that column B is not 0.
So I tried

```
df_list<-keep(df_list,as_mapper(~.x$B!=0))
Error: Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a logical vector of length 6
```

And I received an error warning. Would appreciate if someone can tell me what I did wrong in this function. Or I should not use keep/discard for this case.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to wrap with `any` (if at least one value in 'B' column is not 0) or `all` (if all the values in the column is not 0) to return a single logical output per list element

```
library(purrr)
keep(df_list, ~ any(.x$B != 0))
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#  A B C
#1 4 1 0
#2 5 7 9
#3 6 8 0
```

---

Or with `discard`

```
discard(df_list, ~ all(.x$B == 0))
```

NOTE: `as_mapper` is only needed when we want to make use of the tidyverse lambda call (`~`) outside the tidyverse env

---

Or using `base R` with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) any(x$B != 0), df_list)
```

Or `sapply` to create a logical vector and subset

```
df_list[sapply(function(x) any(x$B != 0))]
```

#### data

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(A = 1:3, B = c(0L, 0L, 0L), C = 4:6), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(A = 4:6, B = c(1L, 7L, 8L), C = c(0L, 9L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

Comment: Just tried three of them! All worked! Thank you so much!